# Converting protobuf Dynamic Message returned by gRPC call into JSON or similar object

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I am making a gRPC call to a server using reflection which returns Dynamic Message as the response message. Now, although this object looks similar to a nested object, its structure is slightly different from a JSON. This makes fetching of values based on fields, like

```
someObject.get(someField)
```

difficult. One way is to parse this message to an object and then fetch the desired values. Any suggestions on parsing here ?

This is the class getting returned :

```
com.google.protobuf.DynamicMessage
```

But, although it looks like a nested JSON, we can't fetch values based on fields.

To have an overview of the shema, this is how the response looks:

```
field1 {
  key1: "value1"
}
field2 {
  key1: "value1"
  key2: value2
  key3 {
    netsed_key_1: "nested_val_1"
    netsed_key_2: "nested_val_2"
  }
  key4 {
    netsed_key_1: "nested_val_1"
    netsed_key_2: "nested_val_2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
FieldDescriptor fieldDescriptor = message.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("someField");
Object value = message.getField(fieldDescriptor);
```

To get a list of all the fields:

```
Map<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor, Object> allFields = message.getAllFields();
```

To get a nested value do this:

```
Message subMessage =
    (Message)message.getField(
        message.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("field3"));
Message subSubMessage =
    (Message)subMessage.getField(
    subMessage.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("key3"));
String subSubSubMessage veryNestedString =
    (String)subSubMessage.getField(
    subSubMessage.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("netsed_key_1"));
```

Comment: Hey John,
Thanks for the response.

I have added a sample schema in the main question so that we can get an idea of the schema we are referring to.
The message.getAllFields() just returns the first level fields, not the nested fields, is there any suggestion how we are going to refer them.

Also, message.getDescriptorForType().findFieldByName("someField"); gives null pointer, as the map has keys in FieldDesriptor format, while we are giving string here.

Comment: Hey John,
I have updated the comment and the question, could you please share some more light there ?

Comment: I was able to resolve the NPE, but still not able to fetch values based on nested keys.

Comment: I am getting the error of unmodifiable list while typecasting to Message: 
Failed to read message., cause=java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList cannot be cast to com.google.protobuf.Message

Comment: In debug mode, without the cast, can you inspect the element types within the UnmodifiableRandomAccessList?

Comment: If the field you are accessing is a repeating field you will need to use `message.getRepeatedField` instead of `message.getField`. Is that the case for `field3` ?